# Inserting PHP into a page

Tags: php

This is probably a very basic PHP problem, but I am complete noob when it comes to PHP, so I will ask this based on my specific problem.

I am using Stripe Checkout and PHP to take card payments on a site. It's set up and working fine. However, what I need to do now is feed the data returned by Stripe (either a successful payment or a transaction error like a card decline) into a page that fits the design of the rest of my site.

For example, at the moment, I have the following PHP for charging a card, reporting success, or catching and reporting an error:

```
try{

  $customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
      'email' => $email,
      'card'  => $token
  ));

  $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
      'customer' => $customer->id,
      'amount'   => $grandtotal,
      'currency' => 'usd',
      'description' => $email
  ));

  echo '<h1>Successfully charged $50.00!</h1>';
}catch(Stripe_CardError $e) {
  // Since it's a decline, Stripe_CardError will be caught
  $body = $e->getJsonBody();
  $err  = $body['error'];

  print('Status is:' . $e->getHttpStatus() . "\n");
  print('Type is:' . $err['type'] . "\n");
  print('Code is:' . $err['code'] . "\n");
  // param is '' in this case
  print('Param is:' . $err['param'] . "\n");
  print('Message is:' . $err['message'] . "\n");
}
?>
```

This has been put together from examples and API documentation and works fine, but obviously it just prints the results on a blank page.

How can I take the pertinent information (essentially the message) and insert it into a 'proper' site page (the rest of the site is just static HTML and CSS) with appropriate styling etc?

Comment: Nope, and unfortunately don't have time to learn :) That's next year's project.

Comment: Then come back after a year.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the cleanest way, but is the basic way how to do it.

```
<html>
  <body>
    Some text<br />
    <?php
      try
      {
        $customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
            'email' => $email,
            'card'  => $token
        ));

        $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
            'customer' => $customer->id,
            'amount'   => $grandtotal,
            'currency' => 'usd',
            'description' => $email
        ));

        echo '<h1 class="resultsuccess">Successfully charged $50.00!</h1>';
      } catch(Stripe_CardError $e) {
        // Since it's a decline, Stripe_CardError will be caught
        $body = $e->getJsonBody();
        $err  = $body['error'];

        echo '<div class="resultfail">';
        echo 'Status is:' . $e->getHttpStatus() . "<br/>";
        echo 'Type is:' . $err['type'] . "<br/>";
        echo 'Code is:' . $err['code'] . "<br/>";
        // param is '' in this case
        echo 'Param is:' . $err['param'] . "<br/>";
        echo 'Message is:' . $err['message'] . "<br/>";
        echo '</div>';
      }
    ?>
    <br />
    Other text
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
      <?php 
         require_once('path/to/phpFileWithCodeToBeExecuted.php')
      ?>
</div>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

Comment: Why not `require` instead of the slower `require_once`?

Comment: At the moment, the PHP in my question is in a file that is run when a form is submitted. How would that work with your example?

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna go out on a limb here and tell you what to do step by step. But first

### preamble

You can use php for templating. Your site must have a templating scheme that you can follow. These templates are usually html with php tags surrounding logic or php "stuff".

### Steps

1. Create a template that will output the final document for your user to see. Leave placeholders for where your dynamic data will be placed

   ```
   <!-- a paragraph that will be populated through php -->
   <p><?php echo $a_name_that_should_make_sense_to_you; ?></p>
   ```
2. Once your template is done your logic should prepare the environment. As an example

   ```
   <?php // this is a php scriptfile that executes logic

   // your logic goes here
   // some of the variables from logic have to reach the template
   $a_name_that_should_make_sense_to_you = 'this is a short paragraph';
   ```
3. Include the template so that it is "*placed*" right next to your logic and, therefore, granting it access to the variables it needs.

   ```
   include 'your/wonderfully/marvelous/template.php';
   ```
4. The raw text from the template will be sent to STDOUT alongside anything that is `echo`ed and `print`ed and `dump`ed as well as any errors thrown

### Addendum

this is just an example of a way to do this, there are better ways, and some answers already given here are great as well

Any questions???? please ask ^^

Comment: Thanks for your input. I plan on learning the basics of dynamic sites with PHP and SQL in the near future. At present, I've solved this problem using a cookie that stores the plain English message returned by the payment server which the confirmation page reads and prints. Works fine.